# The compile process success on compiler fail on online compilers why?

Tags: java, for-loop, input, compiler-errors

I'm using below code in order to make application for winners team, and it's work on compilers e.g Inellij..

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("how many cases");
    int cases = scanner.nextInt();
    if (cases < 1 || cases > 100){
        System.out.println("REenter cases");
        cases =scanner.nextInt();
        return;
    }
    String [] winnerTeams = new String[cases];
    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
       winnerTeams[i] = getWinnersTeam(scanner);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        System.out.println(winnerTeams[i] + "\n");
    }

}

public static String getWinnersTeam(Scanner sc) {
    int bestScore = 0;

    String team = "Nothing entered";
    System.out.println("how many teams");
    int count = sc.nextInt();
    if (count < 2 || count > 100){
        System.out.println("group should be 2++");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    sc.nextLine();
    while (count-- > 0) {
        System.out.println("Entered team,score");

        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String arr [] = line.split(" ");
        // check size - TBD
        if (Integer.parseInt(arr[1]) > bestScore) {
            bestScore = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            team = arr[0];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("nest team is " + team + " with a score of " + bestScore);
   return team;
}
```

but when i run this code on any online compiler i get exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

What I'v do wrong with scanner?

does I missing something, please point me, thanks in advance.

Comment: try to post Complete question! When saying online compiler try to be specific with the hyperlink!!

Comment: @Mr.Arjun I said all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a compiler error, this is a runtime-error.

It (probably) comes from the fact that some online environments don't implement the console, thus you can't write anything to standard input - so no elements for the `Scanner`.

To get the idea: visit https://ideone.com/, select Java and click `stdin` and write ahead the input you would normally give to your app, separated by spaces. For example if you just write `0` there, your app will print `REenter cases` since you only accept cases from `1-100`

Comment: Indeed it's support the command line for example this one https://www.compilejava.net/